# MBP Late 2011 AMD GPU Issue csrutil disable command not found?

Tags: macbook-pro, gpu

I am currently in the process of trying to bring my mighty MBP 2011 back to life as its encountered the dreaded AMD GPU issue.

I probably spent about 7 hours yesterday following various videos and researching all of the forum posts etc on how to disable the AMD GPU so the MBP will only use the Intel one.

I am not looking to do anything to the logic board, only code.

I have followed multiple forums involving the csrutil disable code however my MBP pro keeps telling me that the command was not found. I am entering this code in recovery mode.

I gained access for the desktop for about 20 minutes and tried entering the csrutil status in Terminal (knowing it's not going to work but just to test) and it told me that the SIP is enabled even though the command doesn't exist in recovery mode? It then tells me that I can only input this code in Recovery mode, which doesn't work..

I am running MacOS Sierra 10.12.6.

I've heard that SIP is not on my OS and is on the later OS however I am not sure how to upgrade to a later OS as there is no update available on the AppStore.

I am new to Apple and new to all of this tech stuff however I am determined to bring this back to life.

I understand that their are plenty of posts with this issue open however I can't see anyone explaining why csrutil disable will not work for some people.

Comment: Your MBP runs with 10.7.2 up to 10.13.6. *csrutil* is included in 10.11.0-10.13.6 (and newer systems) and to disable SIP you have to run the disable command in Recovery Mode. So the sw_vers of the Recovery System you are booting from (either disk or Internet) is probably too old (≤10.10.5).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how would I upgrade so I can disable csrutil?

Comment: Boot with shift-cmd-R or cmd-R and try to run csrutil and/or install High Sierra or d/l High Sierra in normal mode.

Comment: Booting with both shift-cmd-R and cmd-R still bounces back with command unknown. Would I download High Sierra on the internet then how would I install it?

Comment: Can anyone else give me some more guidance? Thank you